# Routes for a user controller in a Node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, url-routing

I have a very simple Node application that routes requests to `/users` to the following file:

**users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('models/user');
var sequelizeSuccessHandler = require('lib/sequelizeSuccessHandler');
var sequelizeErrorHandler = require('lib/sequelizeErrorHandler');

router.get('/', function(request, response) {
  User.findAll()
  .then(sequelizeSuccessHandler(response))
  .catch(sequelizeErrorHandler(response));
});

router.post('/', function(request, response) {
  User.create(User.params(request.body))
  .then(sequelizeSuccessHandler(response))
  .catch(sequelizeErrorHandler(response));
});

router.get('/:id', function(request, response) {
  User.findOne({where: {id: request.params.id}})
  .then(sequelizeSuccessHandler(response))
  .catch(sequelizeErrorHandler(response));
});

router.patch('/:id', function(request, response) {
  User.findOne({where: {id: request.params.id}})
  .then(function(user) {
    return user.update(User.params(request.body));
  })
  .then(sequelizeSuccessHandler(response))
  .catch(sequelizeErrorHandler(response));
});

router.delete('/:id', function(request, response) {
  User.findOne({where: {id: request.params.id}})
  .then(function(user) {
    return user.destroy();
  })
  .then(sequelizeSuccessHandler(response))
  .catch(sequelizeErrorHandler(response));
});

module.exports = router;
```

**lib/sequelizeSuccessHandler.js**

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

function successHandler(response) {
  return function(object) {
    response.send(JSON.stringify(object));
  };
}

module.exports = successHandler;
```

**lib/sequelizeErrorHandler.js**

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

function errorHandler(response) {
  return function(error) {
    if (error.constructor == Sequelize.ValidationError) {
      response.status(400).send();
    } else {
      response.status(500).send();
    }
  };
}

module.exports = errorHandler;
```

Looking at `users.js`, you can see that I tried to DRY things up by creating `sequelizeSuccessHandler` and `sequelizeErrorHandler` (I hate those names), but there's still a lot of repetition. I feel like there is a better way to do this.

How can I clean this up?

Comment: the database queries should be done in a separate controller

Answer (score 1):

> Looking at users.js, you can see that I tried to DRY things up by creating `sequelizeSuccessHandler` and `sequelizeErrorHandler` (I hate those names), but there's still a lot of repetition.

I suppose you're talking about these repeated lines in the route handlers:

> ```
>   .then(sequelizeSuccessHandler(response))
>   .catch(sequelizeErrorHandler(response));
> ```

I don't really know Node,
but it seems to me that you could add another helper function:

```
function handle(query, response) {
  query
  .then(sequelizeSuccessHandler(response))
  .catch(sequelizeErrorHandler(response));
});

router.get('/', function(request, response) {
  handle(User.findAll(), response);
});

router.post('/', function(request, response) {
  handle(User.create(User.params(request.body)), response);
});
```

(The names "handle", and "query" might not be the best.)